# C++ try blocks and exception handling

Tags: c++

The code is as following:

```
int main() {
    int a, b;
    while (cin >> a >> b) {
        try {
            if (b == 0)
                throw runtime_error("Can not divide zero!");
            if (a >= 100 || b >= 100)
                throw range_error("a and b can not be over 100");
            cout << a / b << endl;
        } catch(runtime_error err){
            cout << err.what() << endl;
            cout << "\nTry again? Enter y or n" << endl;
            char c;
            cin >> c;
            if (!cin || c == 'n')
                break;
        }
        catch (range_error err2) {
            cout << err2.what() << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I found that when I enter a number greater than 100, as indicated by the code, a `range_error` is thrown. But I wonder why it still displays "Try again? Enter y or n" and functions exactly the same as the first catch block. As in the second catch statement there isn't any code telling the user to input y or n. And if I deleted the relevant code in the first catch statement, this message would not display when `range_error` occurred.

And by the way, if the try block throws two `runtime_errors` which require different handling process, how would the program tell which catch statement to run?

Comment: `std::range_error` is a subclass of `std::runtime_error`, so `catch(std::runtime_error)` catches it too. Have tried catching in the opposite order?

Comment: Is there any reason why you catch your exceptions by value?

Comment: Both gcc clang warn for this [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/44c67613bf8902d0).

Comment: A rule of thumb with exceptions, you always wanna catch the most specific exception first and the most generic last so you don't run into this kind of problems

Comment: Thanks. But I have another question: Is it that there can be only one pair of runtime_error throw and catch in a function? If there are two, the second one will never be reached?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to catch `range_error` first since it is derived from `runtime_error`.  Catching `runtime_error` first also catches `range_error`.

Also, you should catch exceptions by const reference.  By catching them by value you are making copies of them which is unneeded.

I would add one more thing... Generally, you don't want to use exceptions to control program flow as you are doing.